# VBA code to change file format of multiple files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

The following code below changes the file format of multiple files saved as *.xml* to *.xlsx* files. It simply opens the files in a specific folder and "Saves as" *.xlsx*. However I don't know how to make it run on all the files in my target folder. As of now it is only pointing to the 1st file in the folder.

```
Sub m_convertformat()
'
' m_convertformat Macro

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Change the format
         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "S:\Xyz\abc.xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

        End With

    'Save and Close Workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

End Sub
```

Comment: See [Enumerate files in a directory using FileSystemObject](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject/9507/enumerate-files-in-a-directory-using-filesystemobject) or [Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba) (and likely a bunch of others).

Comment: I believe it's how you set `myFile`. Try just `myFile = Dir(myPath)` and add an `If()` statement to see if it's `myExtension` type file.  Right now, that becomes like, `myFile = Dir(C:\Users\Me\myFileFolder\.xls)`?  The answer in @Comintern's second link should direct you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things in the code that need adjusting in order for it to work exactly as the text you wrote described. See the refactored code below.

```
'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xml" `- since you want to open xml files to save as xlsx
```

Then change

```
 'Change the format
         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "S:\Xyz\abc.xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

To

```
   'Change the format
    wb.SaveAs Filename:= wb.Path & "\" Replace(wb.Name,".xml",".xlsx"), _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Then delete this: `End With`